# When does omniture video use trackingServerSecure vs trackingServer?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-analytics

I have the following config flags in my com.omniture.AppMeasurement setup (swc version FAS-3.4.7)

```
trackingServer: "metrics.my-site.com",
trackingServerSecure: "smetrics.my-site.com"
```

and when visiting https://my-site.com and I'm seeing beacons go to metrics.my-site.com instead of smetrics.mysite.com.  The page tracking is reporting to the secure page, but the swf based video metrics are not.  The html5 fallback is also behaving correctly, it's only the swf that has this problem.  (The swf is also being loaded via https)

What determines where the beacons are going and if it's just the parent url, what else could cause this to default to the http beacon url?

Answer (score -2):

Looks like this might work:

```
actionSource = new ActionSource();          
actionSource.ssl = true;
```

Comment: Based on decompiling ActionSource, ssl is the variable that defines which server gets used.  The only call that sets ssl to true/false is "set movie" and the code in "set movie" just tests the url of the movie to see if it's http: or https:.  So if you're just doing tracklinks, there's no other way to get ssl set but to set it yourself.